# How does the word "Talmud" derive from root LMD? Is the word Aramaic?

Tags: hebrew, talmud-gemara, grammar-dikduk, aramaic

I know what "Talmud" means and that it derives from the root Lamed Mem Dalet. But I cannot figure out how the word derives. Is it Aramaic (i.e. not Hebrew) and/or are there any other words that follow the t..w. scheme?

(. is a root letter.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is Hebrew. דתנן ר' יהודה אומר הוי זהיר בתלמוד ששגגת תלמוד עולה זדון. Note that this is a Mishna, and ש to mean 'that/for', instead of ד. You can look up the word in Jastrow.

http://www.tyndalearchive.com/TABS/Jastrow/index.htm

Other words on the same pattern: targum; tafnuk (delicacy).

Comment: Also תרבות, תנחום, תשלום, e.g.

Comment: +1; but although the form is Hebrew, it seems to be a Hebrewing of Aramaic /tal'mu.da/.