# Circumcision exceptions on the rule?

Tags: halacha, time, medicine, brit-milah, baby-infant

If one gives birth to a premature/preterm son, or if the childs weight is to low, for example, would it still be circumcised on the 8th day or are there exceptions to the command?

Comment: no if the brit is threatening. e.g. if there is pb of coagulation or immunity

Comment: Consider marking an answer here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76590/actualizing-avodah-shebalev

Answer (score 3):

If it is a matter of the health of the infant, then the bris is delayed until he is "recovered" from whatever is wrong. It is not an automatic situation but determined by the mohel and the doctor.

[When to Delay a Bris Milah](http://www.mohel-bris.com/delaying-the-bris-milah.html)

> A Bris Milah is never performed if it poses any danger to the infant.
>   The doctor and/or mohel's advice to delay a Bris for health reasons
>   should always be heeded. In case of jaundice (yellow pigmentation of
>   the skin), the bris cannot be performed; it is delayed until the
>   bilirubin in the blood drops to a safe level. The bris may then be
>   performed without endangering the child. In cases of some illnesses, a
>   delay of seven days following full recovery is required. It is
>   forbidden to postpone the bris for any reason other than health of the
>   child, or in order to obtain a proper Mohel. It is the responsibility
>   of the Mohel, in consultation with the doctor and the family, to
>   determine if a delay is necessary according to Jewish law.